# Why to use @Autowired on class in Spring

Tags: spring, autowired

I read about the advantages of using Dependency for interface.

I understand the concept for interface - but why to use @Autowire on class? If we use Autowire on class I know in advance what is the implmeneted class and it's like a regular member of it (without the ability of get to this member)!

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Convenience - you do not need to take care for initializing your components, you save time on typing code and configuration files,

2) Forcing good practices - your components to be autowired must be written to be manageable by Spring and spring will take care about error checking for you and pop all errors. So your code will be organized in component collaborating way.

3) Autowiring will also reduce your effort when your classes/beans will grow and evolve.

Comment: I didn't understand your third reason. Why is it different than a regular bean member?

Comment: From Spring Reference:

"Autowiring can update a configuration as your objects evolve. For example, if you need to add a dependency to a class, that dependency can be satisfied automatically without you needing to modify the configuration. Thus autowiring can be especially useful during development, without negating the option of switching to explicit wiring when the code base becomes more stable."

Comment: BTW - When you call for autowired collaborator Spring is scanning ApplicationCOntex for candidates, hence it takes care about controlling instances which may give you some improvement. However please refer to Spring Reference docs to check when autowiring is not recommended.

Comment: I like autowiring because it lets me use a `@Configuration` annotation (so I can switch implementations of a bean at deployment time without a lot of complex factory code), *but* it reduces my ability to visualize the overall application using STS. Maybe that will be fixed – improved really – in the future, but right now I lack the ability to see some of my beans, which makes writing reports about the application architecture harder. It's all a matter of trade-offs.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `@Autowire` and not call the constructor, you mark the class to be dynamically initialized by the Spring Container. This allows you to set class properties as defined in your spring configuration.

Answer (score 0):

> If we use Autowire on class I know in
>   advance what is the implmeneted class
>   and it's like a regular member of it

When you wire the dependency through XML instead of Annotations, **you also know in advance** in which class are you going to inject it. 
**But You still declare an Interface as dependency**, so you can wire any Implementation of this interface at runtime.

Comment: This was not my question. My question was about wiring classes and not interfaces. As well, XML can be changed with no deployment of the full application like @Autowire